# find a string in an array with pointers

Tags: c

I have a problem, I need to test if a string is present in an other array in C using pointer. I tried this, but it doesn't work, if anyone has any suggestion... here is the code I tried, thank you in advance...

```
/* Like the strstr() function. It returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the string aiguille in the string meule_de_foin.
 * @param meule_de_foin the string to search in
 * @param aiguille the string to find
 * @return a pointer to the first occurrence of the string aiguille in the string meule_de_foin if aiguille is in meule_de_foin, NULL otherwise
 */

const char * IMPLEMENT(indexOfString)(const char *meule_de_foin, const char *aiguille) {
    int isFound; isFound=0;
    int first; first=meule_de_foin;

    while(isFound==0){
        if(*aiguille=='\0' && *meule_de_foin=='\0'){
            isFound=1;
        } else if (*aiguille == *meule_de_foin){
            aiguille=aiguille+1;
            meule_de_foin=meule_de_foin+1;
        }else{
            isFound=2;
        }
    }

    if(isFound==1){
        return (first);
    }else{
        return(NULL);
    }
}

if(isFound==1){
    return (first);
}else{
    return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: It's a lot easier when the code is actually in English.

Comment: Your function only checks if `aiguille` is found at the beginning of `meule_de_foin`.

Comment: `first` should be `const char *`, not `int`.

Comment: Is IMPLEMENT a macro? Please remove the extra lines at the end of the snippet.

Comment: @Ante depends who reads the code :-) Btw "aiguille" is needle, and "meule de foin" is haystack

Comment: @ringø English is a _universal_ language in IT, if you write your code in another language then only people who understand that language can really make out what's it supposed to do. On the other hand a very large majority of developers are suppose to have good understanding of English now days.

Comment: You’re absolutely right about the English thing. It’s a huge project I have to accomplish for school and idk why my teacher thought It funny to name those in French, should’ve translated it, sorry about that.

Comment: @Bob__ I’m not sure if implement is a snippet honestly... this way of declaring function is used before every function déclaration on the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only testing if two strings are completely equal.

You need to stop checking when you reach the end of the search string, even if you're not at the end of the string to search.

And if it's not found, you need to check again starting at the next character, and keep repeating this until you reach the end of the string. So you need another loop around the loop that searches.

```
int isFound = 0;
const char *first;
for (first = meule_de_foin; *first != '\0' && isFound != 1; first++) {
    isFound = 0;
    const char *search = aiguille;
    const char *cur = first;
    while (!isFound) {
        if (*search == '\0') { // End of search string
            isFound = 1;
        } else if (*search != *cur) { // Non-matching character, stop matching
            isFound = 2;
        } else { // Keep matching
            search++;
            cur++;
        }
    }
}

if (isFound == 1) {
    return first;
else {
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I totally get my mistake and how you corrected it, I have a question tho, what does the "true" means in the while loop?

Comment: It just means that the loop keeps repeating forever. Except that the `break` statements inside will end it.

Comment: But I changed it back to your way of testing `isFound`.